# Direct2D Transparency With MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, direct2d

I'm looking to create a child frame (CWnd subclass) that has transparent regions.

However, I can't seem to get the transparency part working. From what I understand, I would need to enable transparency when creating the `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` using the `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE`flag ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605655/gdi-rendering-to-direct2d-id2d1bitmaprendertarget-is-always-transparent)) However, I don't create the render target that way. Instead, I use `EnableD2DSupport()` in my `OnCreate()` method. When I try to clear the render target with `CHwndRenderTarget::Clear(ColorF)` using a color with opacity set to 0.0, the opacity is ignored. I do this in my function handling the `AFX_WM_DRAW2D` message, with the render target taken from the `LPARAM`.

Any ideas on how to get transparency working for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE` means what it says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - the alpha channel is ignored (the drawings are always opaque). The SO question, you've linked targets the opposite problem, when the drawings are always transparent.

As I see, the `EnableD2DSupport()` creates an `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget`, but most probably with a `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE` flag. You need `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED` or `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT`, so you can use the alpha channel.

If possible, create a `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget` manually with the proper alpha mode and then attach it to the `CHwndRenderTarget` with [`CHwndRenderTarget::Attach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg466502.aspx)

Another way (which I would have chosen) is the Direct2D 1.1 way (more precise - [ID2D1DeviceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), managing the whole drawing process manually. For some guidances look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25460140/3962893).